# Issue Converting to Current Syntax

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, xcode8, bridging-header

I'm trying converting to current Swift syntax an application via Xcode 8. During the operation Xcode fill all my hard disk memory (about 80GB!!!) and I can't proceed with it.

This is a quiet-old-application, wrote in Objective-C with some Swift classes. Anyone faced the same issue?

Comment: It's impossible to help you cause you provided no details here. If there are only a few Swift classes, try converting by hand. ObjC hasn't changed in a long time.

Comment: That's it. I'm trying to understand where is the problem. Unfortunately I don't have more information too. I think it's strange that xcode do this.